# I am facing an issue by using a font accessed via a relative URL

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I am using the below font-face rule in my application

```
@font-face{
          font-family: frutilicn;        
          src: url('../fonts/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.eot');  
          src: url('../fonts/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.ttf') format('truetype'); 
     }
```

When I access the page the font style does not work . I am getting an error in firebug like this:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found http://localhost/fonts/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.ttf"

The 'font folder' is in the same folder as the stylesheet and FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.ttf is in the font folder

What does that mean and what do I need to do? 

Thanks.
```

Comment: does it work on absolute linking?

Comment: In absolute linking I am not getting the error which I have mentioned . But the font styles are not reflecting in the webpage.

Comment: Try `url('fonts/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.eot')`

Comment: this also did not work..

Comment: When I placed the 'fonts folder' inside CSS  folder it worked for me.   But I need the fonts folder is in the same folder as the stylesheet.      Thanks..

Comment: Can you provide a link so we can test this (besides localhost)? What directory structure do you need? Do you want this: /index.html, /fonts/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.eot, /css/stylesheet.css?

Answer (score 0):

We put our purchased fonts (which we embed onto the website) in the root of the site, therefore avoiding issues with relative linking.

```
@font-face{
      font-family: 'Frutiger';        
      src: url('/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.eot');  
      src: url('/FrutigerLTW01-47LightCn.woff') format('woff'); 
      font-weight: lighter;
      font-style: normal;
 }
```

Comment: But if you want to switch to Google Fonts, Use Noto Sans as a replacement for Frutiger.